# Not creating new file while output redirection

Tags: bash, unix, shell, shell-script

I'm using this for output redirection:

```
cat filename | grep 'dis' | wc -l > test.txt
```

But I do not want a zero byte file created if no result is found from the grep command.

Is there any way this is possible ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to pipe output from one process to another but only execute if the first has output?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/how-to-pipe-output-from-one-process-to-another-but-only-execute-if-the-first-has) and [Redirect stderr to a file, but create only if any stderr happened?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159046/redirect-stderr-to-a-file-but-create-only-if-any-stderr-happened) (on U&L)

Answer (score 1):

This will only create `test.txt` if the line count is non-zero:

```
grep 'dis' filename | wc -l | { read line; [ "$line" != "0" ] && echo "$line"> test.txt; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an `AWK` flavor.

```
awk 'BEGIN {lc=0}; /dis/ {lc+=1}; END {if (lc > 0) print lc > "test.txt"}' filename
```

This will create "test.txt" only if there is at least one match found.